# MVC 4 + Methods in controller accepting different parameter name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am new to MVC and currently I am using Postman to test out my webapi method functions. I realise that if I specify a different argument in my method from the routing, I will get a

```
"message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'." error
```

in postman. I would like to find out if it is possible to use a different argument name in a controller? Thanks.

```
    [ActionName("DefaultAction")]
// This method won't be callable because the argument name is different from the routing.
    public virtual IEnumerable<CaseComment> Get(int CaseId) 
    {
       // Implementation
    }

    [ActionName("DefaultAction")]
    public virtual HttpResponseMessage Post(int CaseCommentId)
    {
       // Implementation
    }

    Routing:

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "CaseComment",
         routeTemplate: "api/v1/casecomment/{CaseCommentId}/{action}",
         defaults: new { controller = "casecomment", CaseCommentId= RouteParameter.Optional, action = "DefaultAction" }
         );
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you can't do that unless one is [HttpGet] while another is [HttpPost]